# How find the maximum of the value $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln{(a^2_{i}+n-1)}$

Tags: inequality

let $a_{i}\ge -1,i=1,2,\cdots,n$ and such
$$a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{n}=n$$
Find the  maximum of the value 
$$f=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln{(a^2_{i}+n-1})
$$

My try:consider
$$f(x)=\ln{(x^2+n-1)}$$,then $f'(x)=\dfrac{2x}{x^2+n-1}$,and 
$$f''(x)=\dfrac{2(x^2+n-1)-4x^2}{x^2+n-1}=\dfrac{2n-2-2x^2}{(x^2+n-1)^2}$$it seem that $f''(x)$  determine the symbol，so we can't use Jenson inequality to solve it

Comment: The maximum occurs for $a_1=a_2=...=a_{n-1}=-1$ and $a_n=2n-1.$

Comment: How to find it?and How to prove it, Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to solve the problem for $n=2$ and $n=3$ first?

For the general case, application of the Lagrange method should show that there is only one internal critical point (which is a minimum) while the maximum is to be found on the boundary leading to a very similar problem in one lower dimension...